# Waiting time for a response from server using Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I want to make the insertion of a new row using a command like:

```
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
   .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
   })
   .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
   });
```

I need the response to contain the new ID for the newly created user row containing the information for the user Fred Flintstone. However, since this is a DB one, my script might need to wait more for it. How can I control the waiting time for the response from the server? In other words
how could I do to tell javascript Axios command to wait some number of seconds before it triggers an error message due to "no response from the server". Is this possible?

Comment: I meant how could I do to tell javascript Axios command to wait some number of seconds before it triggers an error message due to "no response from the server" ?

Comment: you can create own timeout function that will wait for no of ms that u want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`axios` got a `timeout` property where you can set the number of milliseconds before the request times out.

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user',
  timeout: 8000, // Let's say you want to wait at least 8 seconds
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  }
})
.then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```